# Is it permitted to think about God / Hashem in the bathroom?

Tags: halacha, theology, bathroom

One may not learn Torah in the bathroom, even if the thoughts are not verbally expressed. That made me wonder if it is permitted to think about God. My definition of "thinking about God" would be either thinking about the existence of God or general theology.

Comment: I remember in the Yesod Veshoresh Haavoda, a cavana as "gvurot hashem"

Comment: Don’t think about G-d when your naked yet people always say to think about G-d in everything you do. Ask your rabbi.

Comment: David hamelech did see his Brit and said בבשרי איזה אלקה

Comment: ירושלמי ברכות     נכנס למרחץ ראה את עצמו ערום אמר אוי לי שאני ערום מן המצות כיון שהביט במילה שלו התחיל לקלס להקב"ה.

Answer (score 3):

Chochmat Shelomo to Orach Chayyim 85:2 ([text](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Chokhmat_Shlomo_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.85.2?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he), [pdf](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x453)) concludes that you can think about God in the bathroom.

> אפילו להרהר בד"ת וכו'. נ"ב נסתפקתי אם מותר להרהר בו ית' או לא. ולכאורה יש ללמוד ק"ו דאסור להרהר במציאותו ויכלתו. אך לפמ"ש המקובלים דתפילין דר"ת מותר לשוח בהם שיחת חולין מכח דקדושים ביותר ואין דבר טמא נתפס בהם י"ל מכ"ש בזה כן. ולכאורה נראה לי ראיה לזה מן הש"ס פ"ק דיומא (דף ז' ע"ב) שהביא שם פלוגתא דר"י ור"ש גבי ציץ ואמר שם דטעמיה דר"ש דכתיב והיה על מצחו תמיד דמהו תמיד אילימא תמיד ממש מי לא בעי מינם פורתא מי לא בעי עייל לבה"כ אלא לתמיד מרצה הוא דאתי ור"י ההוא תמיד הוי שלא יסיח דעתו ממנו וכו' וקשה דהו"ל להקשות לר"ש מה יעשה בהך קרא שויתי ד' לנגדי תמיד קשה נמי כן מהו תמיד מי לא בעי מינם פורתא מי לא בעי עייל לבה"כ בשלמא לר"י אתי שפיר דהכוונה שלא יסיח דעתו ממנו אבל לר"ש קשה מה יפרש בזה מהו תמיד ובע"כ מוכח דבמציאותו יתברך מותר להיות מהרהר בו גם בבה"כ גם לא שייך בו מי לא בעי מינם פורתא די"ל דכל החלומות הוי מהרהורי דיומא ואם מחשב בו ית' תמיד גם בלילה הן כן רעיוניו ושייך ביה תמיד ואתי שפיר כנלפענ"ד ודו"ק היטב:‏

His argument is basically this:

On the one hand, if thinking about Torah is forbidden in the bathroom, thinking about God should be more strict, and therefore also forbidden.

On the other hand, the kabbalists say that you're allowed to speak about mundane things in Rabbenu Tam tefillin but not Rashi tefillin, because Rabbenu Tam tefillin are holier and nothing impure is absorbed in them. So it's possible that since God is also holier than Torah, nothing impure is absorbed in him, and so you can think about God in the bathroom.

He tries to prove the latter interpretation is correct by reference to [Yoma 7b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Yoma.7b.5?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he). Rabbi Shim'on holds that the high priest can't literally wear the tsits *always* (in accordance with [Exodus 28:38](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Exodus.28.38?lang=he&aliyot=0)) because sometimes he has to go to sleep or go to the bathroom, so instead he explains the verse to mean that the tsits always atones even when not on the high priest's forehead.

So how would Rabbi Shim'on be able to explain "I put God before me *always*" ([Psalms 16:8](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Psalms.16.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he))? If the verse is interpreted literally, the same question could be asked here: doesn't a person sometimes have to go to the bathroom? Since his non-literal interpretation of "always" doesn't work here, it must be that it is permitted to think about God in the bathroom.

(The reference to this source comes from [here](http://www.haoros.com/archive/index.asp?kovetz=892&cat=11&haoro=4).)